# cache attributes in MMU page table in arm linux

Tags: linux, arm, mmu

I am wondering how the os decides between write back and write through attributes for a page in the MMU page table in Arm v7 and armv8.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you might want to understand what each is. <sup>[Ref1](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Write-through-write-around-write-back-Cache-explained) [Ref2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Write_policies)</sup>

- **Write through** - data written to RAM immediately.
- **Write back** - data written on **eviction**.

It is easier to make a **write through** cache (in hardware) than a **write back**.  For this reason, some older ARM CPUs may have [a hard coded **write through** only cache](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/Kconfig#n759).  ARMv4/5 have [this as an option](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/Kconfig#n494).  By the time ARMv7/8 are around the logic for the **write back** is very small compared to other logic, so the CPU/MMU support both.

There are also some kernel command line options such as **cachepolicy**, **nocache** and **nowb** in [mmu.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/mmu.c); these only apply to [*early boot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688540/page-table-in-linux-kernel-space) and are mainly for older ARM CPUs, but you could still use them for ARMv7/8.

Generally, **WRITEBACK** is highly valuable as most systems have SDRAM which gives a bonus for writing multiple entries at one time.  Often code performs *read-modify-write* cycles; perhaps multiple times on the same memory or structure.  A typical *cache line* corresponds well to an SDRAM burst length (no coincidence).

There are some cases such as an LCD with DMA where you may wish to use **WRITETHROUGH**, so typically these options are chosen by a kernel allocator.  It will choose the correct property to the non-architecture API.

User space would always want and get **WRITEBACK** memory.  It maybe possible that some `mmap` LCD frame buffer is **WRITETHROUGH**, but it is more possible that it is un-cached.

> I am wondering how the os [linux] decides between write back and write through attributes for a page in the MMU page table in Arm v7 and armv8.

The decision depends on the use of the memory.  Most frequently the **WRITEBACK** mode will be used in user-space except for some rare instances where a drivers memory might be exposed.  Ie, for memory that is only used by CPUs in the system, **WRITEBACK** is always best.  It is only when there is something else looking at the memory (like an LCD DMA) where the **WRITETHROUGH** will be better.  For the LCD DMA, you want the stuff you write to memory to be displayed on screen immediately.

Comment: Oddly enough, writes to SDRAM are often faster than reads (for the CPU).  If the entire cache is *write through*, then a cache line is never *dirty* and the cache is much simpler.  So at some point people did make ARM hardware that only supported one mode.

Comment: I am not an expert in ARM64 by any means.  However, the [arm64 mmu.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c) seems to follow the plain ARM version; your ARMv8 can be used in both modes.